# How to create an aggregated event in firebase (with automatically fired events from SDK)?

Tags: ios, firebase, events, firebase-analytics

We're currently fighting with a special problem: We need to create one custom aggregated event called "superevent" that includes more events/subevents in itself.

All manually created custom subevents (buttons, clicks..) is easy to attach, the problem is with events like in_app_purchases; app_store_subscription_convert; app_store_subcription_renew (which are automatically fired from SDK)

How to locate/catch these specific events and attach them into one aggregated event?

Thanks a lot for your help!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3cvH.png)

Comment: I don't think it's going to be possible to do anything to change the way automatic events work.